# Show some values into datagridview instead of Textboxes

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, web-scraping

I am scraping a web page and I show the most of values into a datagridview and just three values into textboxes. I'd like to show them into datagridview too but I don't know how I can do it. 
This is my code:

**Form1.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Bet> Bets;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1_Load_1();
        dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += DataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private Bet SelectedBet { get; set; }

    private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            SelectedBet = (Bet) dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
            if (SelectedBet.Odds.Count > 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = SelectedBet.Odds[0];
                textBox2.Text = SelectedBet.Odds[1];
                textBox3.Text = SelectedBet.Odds[2];
            }
        }
    }

    private void LoadInfo()
    {
        var url = "http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/australia/northern-nsw/results/";
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);

        Bets = new List<Bet>();

        // Lettura delle righe
        var Rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

        foreach (var row in Rows)
        {
            if (!row.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("rtitle"))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.InnerText))
                    continue;

                var rowBet = new Bet();
                foreach (var node in row.ChildNodes)
                {
                    var data_odd = node.GetAttributeValue("data-odd", "");

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data_odd))
                    {
                        if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("first-cell"))
                        {
                            rowBet.Match = node.InnerText.Trim();
                            var matchTeam = rowBet.Match.Split(new[] {'-'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            rowBet.Home = matchTeam[0];
                            rowBet.Host = matchTeam[1];
                        }


                        if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("result"))
                        {
                            rowBet.Result = node.InnerText.Trim();
                            var matchPoints = rowBet.Result.Split(new[] {':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            int help;
                            if (int.TryParse(matchPoints[0], out help))
                            {
                                rowBet.HomePoints = help;
                            }
                            if (matchPoints.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(matchPoints[1], out help))
                            {
                                rowBet.HostPoints = help;
                            }
                        }


                        if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("last-cell"))
                            rowBet.Date = node.InnerText.Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowBet.Odds.Add(data_odd);
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowBet.Match))
                    Bets.Add(rowBet);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load_1()
    {
        LoadInfo();

        if (Bets.Count > 0)
        {
            SelectedBet = Bets[0];

            dataGridView1.DataSource = Bets;
            if (SelectedBet.Odds.Count > 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = SelectedBet.Odds[0];
                textBox2.Text = SelectedBet.Odds[1];
                textBox3.Text = SelectedBet.Odds[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Bet.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Bet
    {
        public string Match { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public List<string> Odds { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Home { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int HomePoints { get; set; }
        public int HostPoints { get; set; }

    public Bet()
    {
        Odds = new List<string>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        String MatchInfo = String.Format("{0}: {1} -> {2}", Date, Match, Result);
        String OddsInfo = String.Empty;
        foreach (string d in Odds)
            OddsInfo += " | " + d;

        return MatchInfo + "\n" + OddsInfo;
    }

}
}
```

**EDIT:** Check the pic below:

[image]

I want to delete the textboxes and I'd like to add three more columns to show values there.

**EDIT2:** Every row has different textboxes value, When I scrape data I'd like to get that value and put them together the others.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What I understand is that you put some data into a dataGridView, and the selected item in the grid gets it's content shown in the three textBoxes. What do you mean you'd like to show them in the dataGridView too? Aren't they there already?

Comment: A DGV i s always a grid, so you need a row and a column for the extra data. For free form placement you could nest the textboxes or move them over the empty space, though.

Comment: Every row has different textboxes value, When I scrape data I'd like to get that value and put them together the others

Comment: I apologize for my sudden absence and I still don't have much time as of now. I will return later, but until then, can you post how you bind your data from the website to the dataGridView? Do you simply bind the list of Bet classes to the dataGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work? Add to your `Bet.cs` class:

```
public string odd1
{ 
    get { return Odds[0]; }
    set { Odds[0] = value; }
}

public string oddX
{ 
    get { return Odds[1]; }
    set { Odds[1] = value; }
}

public string odd2
{ 
    get { return Odds[2]; }
    set { Odds[2] = value; }
}
```

Make sure to call these ONLY when their respective odd has been added to the list. If the odd is not added, you'll get an exception saying `Index out of bounds`.

I believe these values would show up.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

"I don't understand how I can apply your code. Could you explain it please?". Of course. Do it like this:

```
class Bet
{
    public string Match { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public List<string> Odds { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int HomePoints { get; set; }
    public int HostPoints { get; set; }

    public string odd1 // Here
    {
        get { return Odds[0]; }
        set { Odds[0] = value; }
    }

    public string oddX // Here
    {
        get { return Odds[1]; }
        set { Odds[1] = value; }
    }

    public string odd2 // Here
    {
        get { return Odds[2]; }
        set { Odds[2] = value; }
    }

    public Bet()
    {
        Odds = new List<string>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        String MatchInfo = String.Format("{0}: {1} -> {2}", Date, Match, Result);
        String OddsInfo = String.Empty;
        foreach (string d in Odds)
            OddsInfo += " | " + d;

        return MatchInfo + "\n" + OddsInfo;
    }

}
```

I changed the three values' types to string and not int. Since the list `Odds` is a list of strings.

**Edit 2**

Can you try this instead?

```
public string odd1
{ 
    get { return (Odds.Count >= 3) ? Odds[0] : "error"; }
    set { if (Odds.Count >= 3) Odds[0] = value; }
}

public string oddX
{ 
    get { return (Odds.Count >= 3) ? Odds[1] : "error"; }
    set { if (Odds.Count >= 3) Odds[1] = value; }
}

public string odd2
{ 
    get { return (Odds.Count >= 3) ? Odds[2] : "error"; }
    set { if (Odds.Count >= 3) Odds[2] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am sorry I don't understand how I can apply your code. Could you explain it please? when you can, of course. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Almost perfect! :) just a little thing: I see values that I want but when I scroll down I get an error: "Index out of range . Requested non-negative value and less than the size of the collection ."

Comment: @Marci Can the user add a row to the dataGridView? If that option is enabled, then the "adding row" will count as an actual row and return an error because the "Odds" list inside the row's bound item is empty. Disable that in the visual editor. **Edit: If that doesn't work, then I have another solution**.

Comment: I did it now but I still get this error. I see if I scroll a little I don't get error, but when I am almost in the final of rows It shows me error. if you can help me :9 in the meantime I give you the point, you deserve it

Comment: @Marci "**Marci** boku" for the accept :D. I made an update

Comment: @Marci Glad I could help. Happy coding!